# It it safe to use Tor in Windows safe-mode with networking?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, security

Is it even safer to use Tor in Windows safe-mode with networking than using Tor in Windows normal mode..

Answer (score 0):

It is not more save if you use Tor in either normal or save mode in windows. Windows save mode (with or without networking) is only used to trace problems with your OS or the devices you have in your computer. So you can backtrack and fix the problem. On this site https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001563.htm you can see what windows save mode actually does.